# Postgres Streaming Replication Bandwidth Estimation

Tags: postgresql, streaming, replication

Is there a standard way of estimating what total bandwidth requirements are between a primary and replica using streaming replication?
I understand we can take the size and number of the WAL files but I also understand that using streaming replication data is propagated ahead of the WAL file being filled so I assume that there is a streamed + WAL file type calculation to perform.
Short of tracking the data at the network level is there a rough way to calculate the requirement?

Thanks

Simon

Comment: "I assume that there is a streamed + WAL file type calculation to perform"  There is no reason to do both across a slow network.  If you want the WAL files archived at the site of the replica, you could just set archive_mode to 'always' on the replica , and so archive files from the streaming rather than sending the same data twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WAL information is not transferred using log file shipping, but it is still the same WAL. So the amount of WAL written to the log files is a good measure for the required bandwidth.

Comment: Of course, you can also throw TLS compression on top of that, which in my case saved roughly 60%, but it has become increasingly tricky to achieve: https://www.percona.com/blog/2020/02/13/compression-of-postgresql-wal-archives-becoming-more-important/#comment-10971814